# How to download file from links with Japanese characters

Tags: android, unicode, encoding, download, non-ascii-characters

I'm having trouble loading `PDF` files with Japanese characters, since I'm using `MuPDF` library my implementation is to download the `PDF` first from the link then open it with `MuPDF` from the SDcard. Now it cannot be opened since the `PDF` was not downloaded in the first place.

Here's my code:

```
    try {
    URL url = new URL(path[0]);
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.connect();
    // getting file length
    int lengthOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();

    // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
            url.openStream(), 8192);

    String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(pdfUrl);
    pdfFileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(pdfUrl, null, fileExtension);       

    // Output stream to write file
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/SAMPLE/" + pdfFileName);

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        // publishing the progress....
        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
        publishProgress(""
                + (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile));

        // writing data to file
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    // flushing output
    output.flush();

    // closing streams
    output.close();
    input.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
}
```

It can download successfully any PDF source links except those with Japanese characters.

Comment: Just come to note that `getFileExtensionFromUrl()` is buggy because unicode filename will simply return "". Related bug report can be found here (unresolved for 7 years !): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5510